# swagger response for multiple object json data

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, swagger-2.0, suppress-warnings

i have developed an `node API`, now im using `swagger` to create `Documentation` for this API, but im `stuck` in the `response part`, please help me to write response for this `json` result,

```
    [
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -79.90295559,
            36.05593626
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "id": "f2e08a02-9be9-468d-9bae-b83118ef5110",
          "esri_id": "518",
          "name": "Greensboro et al, NC",
          "panelCount": 1,
          "tot": 790523
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current `swagger` response code is like this,

```
responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Successful response
          # A schema describing your response object.
          # Use JSON Schema format
          schema:
            title: User Authentication
            type: array
            items:
              title: token
              type: object
```

i dont know how to write response `with type to each object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the JSON structure in "Definitions" and refer that in the schema

```
responses:
    # Response code
    200:
      description: Successful response
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/userAuthentication'


definitions:
  -userAuthentication:
    title: User Authentication
    type: array
    items:
      title: token
      type: string
```

If you want token as a JSON then define it and refer.